# How to filter data from datatable according to columns suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

If I have a data table which have `columns with suffix "_"` of the same data type int.

How to get the data where all these columns equal some value say `1` through LINQ .

EX :

```
emp_num  day_   penalty_   role_  abscence

23       12       1          2       true
24        1       1          1       true
76        2       5          1       false
55        1       1          1       false
```

---

I want to get result like this :

```
24        1       1          1       true
55        1       1          1       false
```

because the datatable columns count is variable ,i want some generic way to project over these columns in some way like this :

```
DT.AsEnumerable().Where(all columns with suffix "-" = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var columns = DT.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(int) && c.ColumnName.EndsWith("_"))
    .ToList();
var query = DT.AsEnumerable().Where(row => columns.All(c => row.Field<int>(c) == 1));
```

The `columns` variable is not strongly needed. `ToList` call can be removed and the columns query can be embedded inside the row query, but for efficiency it's better to be extracted in a list in advance as in the above snippet.